# Multisite install - Create each domain with its own directory

Tags: multisite, installation

I am rather new to WordPress and trying to install a multisite install where I have my main WP install in \var\www\html and each new site/domain I create would be created in its own folder. So what I am looking for is:

- site1.com - main site in \var\www\html\
- site2.com - site in \var\www\html\site2.com\
- site3.com - site in \var\www\html\site3.com\

I'm thinking this should this be a directory install but I may haveto do something with .htacccess or httpd.conf in order for things to work how I'd like?

The WP multisite install (4.6.1) is on AWS running Ubuntu 14.04. I included the httpd.conf file from Apache config.

Comment: what is called "multisite" in wordpress is a unique installation on e.g. "/var/www/html" and all domains are linked to this directory. then WP send custom content depending of the domain. what you want to do is 3 separate installation of wordpress which is not usefull if you don't have specific needs

Comment: Guess I was  a little confused on how it all worked. I thought by default it would create it's own directory for each domain I created to store the uploads and what not but that is not quite how it works. My biggest issue was a DNS problem so only the main site was resolving. Everything seems good now.

Comment: I need help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251212/how-to-reinstall-wordpress-multisite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup you want will give you three isolated installations. The benefit of using WordPress Multisite is that from one login you can access all three sites, also it allows you to do upgrades and control the plug-ins and themes for all the sites. Basically it's like having your own wordpress.com. Now depending if it is a new install or not it will define your structure.

Please refer to the WordPress Codex for more details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network